# Compute integral using residue theorem: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^6}dx$.

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I am trying to compute this integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^6}dx$ using the residue theorem. To do so, I am integrating $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+z^6}$ in the frontier of this sector of a circle: $\{z:|z|<R, 0<arg(z)<\pi/3\}$.

I kwo how to deal with the integrals over the horizontal segment of the sector and over the arc of the circle. My problem is the "diagonal segment". When I parametrize it, I do not get something easy to integrate. How could I approach this?

(The path of integration was suggested in my book, so I do not think that is the problem).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paramertic form is $z=r(\frac {1 +\sqrt 3} 2), 0<r<R$. The integral on this line becomes $(\frac {1 +\sqrt 3} 2) \int_0^{R} \frac r {1+r^{6}}dr$ since $(\frac {1+\sqrt 3 } 2)^{6}=1$. Now you get $[1-\frac {1 +\sqrt 3} 2)]\int_0^{\infty} \frac r {1+r^{6}}dr=$ $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues.